Throughout and through. How to use them?
We use "through" when something is "around" us. For instance: through a tunnel or through high grass but not through a road. Does the same rule apply to "throughout" that I could say "his things were scattered throughout the forest" but not "his things were scattered throughout the sidewalk" because "sidewalk" is a flat surface?

In those contexts where they essentially mean the same as through, both throughout and all through are just "intensified" versions of the base word. Obviously there are contexts where they don't mean the same thing, such as I met my wife through a dating agency, The bullet passed right through his arm, He got through his inheritance in under a year,...

"Through" means from one side to the other. So a tunnel goes through a mountain because it goes in one side and out the other.
"Throughout" means in every part or space possible. So we would say things were scattered throughout a forest to mean they were in all directions and in many places.

the bullet went through his body.
the cancer had spread throughout his body.

You're quite right that a flat surface is different and neither suits this. You could instead say something was "strewn across" or "all across" the sidewalk if they were in all directions, or "all along" the sidewalk if they were broadly in a line from one end to the other. You might also say "all around" to mean a more random distribution.

what about my example with "sidewalk"?

@user203412 you're right, i missed that point. I've added in a point to cover this

similarly we wouldn't say "across/ all across the tunnel " if we mean from one end to the other. What if we mean from the left side"wall of the tunnel to the right side/wall. I mean perpendicularly. Is then using across with "tunnel" correct?

@user203412 If you say someone ran across the tunnel, it would sound a little odd, but it would be fairly unambiguous, referring to the same basic notion as running across the road: moving from one side to the other, perpendicular to the main axis.
